# How to use Gradle with ADT in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, gradle, build.gradle, adt

I have an Android project in Eclipse and I need to use some libraries in it, but I can't add them to the project because I can't find `build.gradle` file, please help me to make my Android project support Gradle like Android Studio

Answer (score 0):

you could install [Eclipse Buildship](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship) for Gradle support.

or import the project to [Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/).

in both cases the `ant` build would need to be converted.

Comment: Thanks for answer, and what I will do after